# How to make chromium-browser show in only one virtual desktop?

Tags: window-manager, chromium, lubuntu, workspaces, openbox

I am now using the "Lubuntu version based on lxde", which is based on "openbox".

What frustrats me a lot is that the **chromium-browser** is omnipresent on both workspces. I have tried to modified `~/.configure/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` to set the **omnipresent** option *chromium-browser* application no and reconfigure *openbox-lubuntu*,however there seems no effect.

Does anybody have similar experience?What's your solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay go to you settings in chromium-browser and select "Use system title bar and borders" in "Personal stuff" section, and then right-click on the window of chromium and select "Desktops>Desktop 1" instead of "All desktops"

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the Chromium entry in your task bar (or dock) there is a menu option called "Move to Workspace" select that and then select any option but "All workspaces". This will put it in only one of your workspaces.